# How much available space per game in the Steam Cloud?

Tags: steam, steam-cloud

Is there a way to find out how much available space does a game have in the Steam Cloud (it seems that this varies depending on the game)? Also, is there a way to see how much of the available space is already used up (except by manually checking save game folders on your hard drive)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your Steam library, you can right-click a title and select Properties. From here, select the Updates tab.

In the bottom part of the window, you can see exactly how much space is used for that game, and how much storage that game has left. Here's what it says on my computer for [SpaceChem](http://store.steampowered.com/app/92800/):

[image: Properties dialog for SpaceChem: Steam Cloud: 1.27 MB stored / 94.10 MB available]

As you mentioned yourself, the permitted size does indeed vary per game; e.g. [Portal 2](http://store.steampowered.com/app/620/) has 1 GB available.

This information is also available even if the title isn't currently installed.

Comment: can't believe I looked everywhere but game_name->properties.. thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Inside the Steam library, right click on a game and select "properties", then open the "updates" tab and you'll find both the total space available for that game and how much has been used.

[image]

Total space varies depending on title, for instance it's 100 MB for Half-Life 2 and 1024 MB for Team Fortress 2. 
Anyway, when you reach this limit your oldest saves will be automatically removed from the cloud (but not from your hard drive) to make space for new ones.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Steam game count VS limit]

By my estimate steam provides aproximately 108MB per game in my library.

1024mb*93gb = 95252MB, / 876 games = 108mb each.

But, we know from the other posts that games can be 1GB(portal 2) or 100MB (Half-life2)

So, the minimum is 100mb, but valve does whatever they want, so some titles will vary as neccesary.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Steam Cloud Online page](https://store.steampowered.com/account/remotestorage), and log in with your Steam credentials. All your backed up files appear here and can be downloaded. To know how much is allowed I usually search for it online. But it doesn't really matter as Steam seems to control what is backed up. As an example, my Skyrim saves are 3 GB (on my local drive). Only ~60 MB (the last few saves) are being backed up.

HOWEVER: The here mentioned method in your local Steam via game/properties does show a **different** number. It claims 142 MB were being saved. One number is a lie (as is the cake).

Answer (score 0):

This information has moved to another tab.
Inside the Steam library, right click on a game and select "properties", then open the "General" tab