# What happens when you use all of your steam cloud save space?

Tags: steam, steam-cloud

When I'm playing, I like to quick-save a lot!

Recently I've started playing a game that generates a new save file each time I hit the quick-save key and thus I've accumulated a large amount of save files.

This is no problem for my hard-drive since I have the space to spare but at this rate I'll end up using all of my steam cloud save space.

What happens when you use up all your space?
Do the old saves get deleted from the cloud to make space for the new saves or does Steam simply stop backing up saves to the cloud?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I contacted Steam Support and asked the same question.
Here's their reply:

> When cloud storage is full, Steam will no longer be able to add new files.

Answer (score 5):

By the looks of it, it's per game, and you can follow [the steps here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/78920/how-much-available-space-per-game-in-the-steam-cloud) to see how much you've used up and how much you have left.

Having a read [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/2dkss5/well_i_finally_used_up_all_my_steam_cloud_storage/) it seams that when it's full - its full and nothing gets deleted ...

Since your hard can support it (and to be honest save files aren't that large) I'd disable Cloud Save for that game.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I did know it was per game and I've checked the space it was consuming otherwise I'd never came up with this question. In fact I had roughly 30% of the allowed space used in the first 2h of play (and this game takes at least 40h to complete). I don't want to disable the cloud save because I want my saves (at least the most recent ones) to be backed up. Thus I need to be aware of what Steam does to know if I have to manually manage my save files or if Steam backs up the most recent saves by itself. I'm not sure if screenshot space is the same as save-file space.